# How to Create Custom Key Binded Snippets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a huge Sublime Text user, and learned ways to improve my productivity using customizations in Sublime text. But as  VScode is becoming popular day by day, wanted to check if there is any way which I can bind the shortcut keys to the custom actions.

For example, I select a word **ABC** in any file in VSCode and hit CTRL+B, and it places my own defined values around it like it should become

```
<b>ABC</b>
```

I had created the following snippet in Sublime Text, which when I wrote in Visual Studio Code - **keybindings.json** nothing worked.

```
{
    "keys": [
        "ctrl+b"
    ],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "<b>${0:$SELECTION}</b>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "resourceExtname == .html",         // this is optional
    "args": {
      "snippet": "<b>${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</b>"
    }
},
```

The optional `when` clause is if you want to limit the snippet's operation to `.html` files.

More general though is to use the emmet command which is built-in: `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation` in the command palette.  Select your text, open the command palette, find that command and trigger it - type `b` or whatever your element is and it will wrap the selected text with the opening and closing elements.

[Note that there is a command `workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility` already bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>, but the snippet above version seems to take precedence - meaning you lose the `toggleSidebarVisibility` keybinding functionality - that may be acceptable to you?]

Comment: Can we also use the multi cursor functionality in this like I just created a snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/d2xekn0w/ but i need to have the cursor placed after function and within if function exists https://i.imgur.com/KLmqqGn.png so that i can write a function name without writing it 2 times

Comment: Yes, see tabstops: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops.  Just use the same tabstop - like `$1` in both places and you will get two cursors.  If I understand you correctly...